# What is the difference between Coding and Programming?

Tags: knowledge-representation

In our daily life we use both coding and programming for the same meaning. I want to know the difference between these terms (If any).

If they are used for different meanings than please anyone can aware us about it, So we can correct ourselves.

Comment: They are synonymous.

Comment: ...or not.  Really, I don't think there is anybody in charge of the official definition of those words.

Comment: How about the difference between Computer Science and programming? That's a more pertinent question. A lot of people, including most of the freshman CS students at my university, consider them to be synonymous. (There is obviously so much more to CS than programming.)

Comment: @jameslarge There's nobody "in charge" but words have widely-accepted meanings.

Answer (score 2):

They are mostly synonymous. In that profession you can be called, or call yourself, a coder, a programmer, a software developer, or a software engineer. They all do the same job. If you call yourself an "engineer", then in many jurisdictions you would have to have training, pass some stringent exams, and may have legal responsibilities for the results - people calling themselves "software engineers" usually ignore that.

The name used usually goes with some expectations. Someone called a "coder" or "programmer" is usually expected to write code (also called programming), with no expectations of the actual outcome. A "software developer" is someone who is expected to produce complete, working, usable software as the result of his work. A "software engineer" is usually someone who fancies a nice title.

"Coder" is often used as a pejorative. Usually by people who couldn't do it themselves if their life depended on it.

Answer (score 1):

They are synonymous. Programming is the act of writing "source code". Coding is just short for "source code" writing. As someone else stated, nobody has ownership of official definitions of these slang terms, so take any answer with a grain of salt.

If you had, however, asked me the difference between "programming" and "software engineering", then I'd say there is a big difference. Programming is something any hack can do to create a website or small software. Software engineering is a much deeper process which involves designing your software, developing an architecture, then coding it, and testing it afterward. It's like comparing an automotive engineer to a mechanic.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that they are mostly synonymous; but in my experience:

**Coding** is used in less formal contexts (e.g. *coding competitions*, *coding challenge*, *coding snippets*, ...) and it usually refers to building small specific functions/procedures in a specific language or to implementation details.

**Programming** is used in broader and more formal contexts and it often  implies more "high levels" concepts/activities (e.g. *programming paradigms*, *programming methodologies*, ...)